# Selecting SQLite3 data using index positions stored in variables

Tags: sqlite, python-3.7

I am trying to use index positions from 2 drop down menu selections in order to select my table and then select the correct row in the grade column...this should then return the value in the prefix column to a variable.

I have the following code...

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('codes.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('')

def material_code(self):

    tableType = self.comboBox.currentText() #drop down to select table
    tablegrade = self.comboBox_2.currentText() #drop down to select the grade of material
    tableType = tableType.lower()
    tablegrade = tablegrade.lower()

    c.execute('SELECT prefix FROM ' + tableType + ' WHERE grade = ' + tablegrade)

    prefix_code = conn.fetchone()
    print(prefix_code)

    conn.commit()
```

EDIT:

[image: db table setup]

Comment: Do you really have one table per material instead of a single table for all of them? Weird. Anyways, show a sample table definition and contents, and what you expect an example value of `comboBox_index2` to fetch. And read up on how to bind values to parameters instead of including them directly in query strings (can't avoid that with table names though...)

Comment: ok solved...i was over complicating my code. i removed a chunk and corrected my cursor connection to c.fetchone() and now i have my return working.